# Visual Studio 2010 1 Class Library Project Compile 2 DLLs (.NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution with a class library project.  What I want to do is compile 2 DLLs on build.  I want to compile against .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 respectively.  Something like below.

myproject\bin\debug\3.5\assembly.dll

myproject\bin\debug\4.0\assembly.dll

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'can write a simple problem to execute on each build, it simply does:

1. make a copy of your working project file (*.csproj, *.vbproj, etc.)
2. edit the target info from 4.0 to 3.5 (or from 3.5 to 4.0) and update other related properties, it should be simple enough.
3. call msbuild.

I've used this approach before for different purpose.

Comment: No clue where to start with this... are you saying modify the Post Build Event to do this for me?

Comment: @aherrick Yes, in Post Build Event.

Comment: Jeffery do you have any sample code on how this might work?  Never worked with Post Build Event before.

Comment: You can begin with the most simply case. It runs windows command. You can start doing "copy", "del", "move", then try to execute some program with arguments like "myprogram.exe helloworld". You can also use macros, their's a button beside the box to help.

Comment: This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: cool... but it doesn't look like it is easy to change the target framework?

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult. You can make a copy of csproj file, change the the target in VS then diff with the original one.

Comment: I get the making a copy of the CSPROJ file, no problem.  But how can I write a step that will then automatically edit that copied CSPROJ file to change the TargetFramework node?

Comment: What I did before is writing a simple console program and execute it in the Post Build Event.

Comment: Not getting very far with this... do you have a simple example solution which does what you describe?

Comment: Sorry I don't have samples by hand. What I did before is to do some change to the target binaries. It's simple, just write a console app, do some text/xml manipulation, then call it in post build event.

Answer (score 0):

The target framework is part of the application project settings that cannot depend on the configuration (unlike build settings).

I'm afraid you will have to create a separate project for each framework version.